# Elasticsearch python library, update if exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I want to update a document in an index if that document is present, op_type="update" in the bulk operation actions fails with an error. I'm not sure while performing the update operation that the document is already present with the index. Is op+type="update" only allowed if the document already exists in the index?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `op_type=update` will raise a `document_missing_exception` exception if the document you want to update doesn't already exist in the index. You can, however, choose to ignore this exception by passing `raise_on_error=False` to the python bulk helper. But be sure to process the return value of the bulk request in case an unexpected indexing error occurs.

Here's an example:

```
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

URL = "http://localhost:9200"
ES = Elasticsearch(URL)

# drop index if it exists
ES.indices.delete("twitter", ignore=400)

# create the index
ES.indices.create("twitter", {
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "tweet" : {
            "properties" : {
                "text" : { "type" : "text" }
            }
        }
    }
})

# define the actions
actions = [
    {
        '_op_type': 'create',
        '_index': 'twitter',
        '_type': 'tweet',
        '_id': "A",
        'doc': {'text': 'test it!!!!'}
    },
    {
        '_op_type': 'create',
        '_index': 'twitter',
        '_type': 'tweet',
        '_id': "B",
        'doc': {'text': 'test it, B!' }
    },
    {
        '_op_type': 'update',
        '_index': 'twitter',
        '_type': 'tweet',
        '_id': "A",
        'doc': {'text': 'update it!'}
    },
    {
        '_op_type': 'update',
        '_index': 'twitter',
        '_type': 'doc',
        '_id': "C",
        'doc': {'text': 'Update should fail, this doc has not been created yet'}
    }
]

# bulk update the index.  Set raise_on_error=False to avoid raising the "document_missing_exception"
# CAUTION! you'll want to carefully parse the output of this in case an unexpected exception is thrown
result = helpers.bulk(ES, actions, raise_on_error=False)

# parse the return result of bulk to account for all errors.
```